# Android Studio: NoClassDefFoundError: packagename.NameActivi$y

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

I have 3 days wit this error. This project was developed in Eclipse, and now I have to take this project to Android Studio. Every activity in the project throw to me this exception

```
16658-16692/com.shippify.co E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4999
    Process: com.shippify.co, PID: 16658
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.shippify.co.SplahsActivity$1$1
            at com.shippify.co.SplahsActivity$1.run(SplahsActivity.java:104)
```

And this is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'
            }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath ('com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0');
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.15.2'
        // 2. Add a reference to the Crashlytics Gradle plugin to your dependencies.
        //classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+' //plugin
        //classpath ('com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3');
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'crashlytics' // Apply the plugin

    repositories {

        // 4. Add the Maven repository
       // maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        mavenCentral()
    }


dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    //compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    //compile project(':libraryviewpager')
    compile project(':Volley')
    compile project(':Uni Image Lod Lib')
    compile project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
    compile project(':libraryforcalender')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar' // New Library
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
    //compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.4'
    //compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    //Add to the SDK in the project
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
        buildTypes{
            debug { //Ask about this!
                ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            }
        }
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }
        dexOptions{
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }
```

And this is my Manifest File:

```
   <application tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
        android:name="com.shippify.co.ApplicationController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_200x200"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.shippify.co.SplahsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Obviously, I'm not put all the manifest file because it's too long.
Please, help me with this!